# Semantische Vokalvielfalt

Tags: vowel, curiosity

Mit semantischer Vokalvielfalt meine ich sinnvolle Wörter, die sich nur an einem Polyphthong (Vokal, Diphthong, Triphthong, auch inklusive Dehnungs-e, aber nicht Hiat) unterscheiden. Die Aussprache ist egal, es zählt nur die Schreibung, wobei Groß-Kleinschreibung ignoriert wird.

[Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15183/2594) ist die analoge Frage mit Variationen der Aussprache.

Ein Beispiel wäre *br*t*, das folgende Varianten hat:

Alle Grundvokale, einer sogar auch mit Dehnungs-e:

- *brat* – Konjugation von *braten*
- *Bret* –  Kurzform von *Wildbret*
- *Brit* – Kurzform von *Brite*
- *briet* – Konjugation von *braten*
- *Brot* – Des Deutschen meistgeschätztes und am schlechtesten bezahltes Nahrungsmittel.
- *Brut* – Abkommenschaft

Außerdem 2 von 3 Umlauten:

- *Brät* – Inhalt einer Bratwurst vorm Grillen.
- *brüt* – Konjugation von *brüten*

Und auch noch 2 der 3 Hauptdiphthonge:

- *Braut* – ein Teil eines Hochzeitspaares
- *breit* – in einer Dimension weit ausgedehnt

Welche Wörter haben eine größere semantische Vokalvielfalt?

Comment: Zug, zack, zag (von zagen), zog, zuck (von zucken), zick (von zicken) zög (von ziehen), zock (von zocken) , zeck (von Zecke), zeug, zeig

Comment: Phonologisch /bri:t/ = <Brit> = <briet> und regional /bre:t/ = <Bret> = <Brät> = <brät>. Es fehlt /brɛt/  = <Brett>.

Comment: ich fände es interessanter, wenn es um Wörter ginge, die vom selben Stamm abgeleitet sind, wie z.B. _Lage_, _lege_, _liege_ (mehr als eine Dreier-Gruppe fällt mir im Moment nicht ein, aber es müsste mindestens eine Vierer-Gruppe geben)

Comment: Ich habe es vielleicht überlesen, aber: *Was ist eigentlich die Frage?*

Comment: @WalterTross... zog, zög, zieh, zug

Comment: @Vogel612 "Gibt es ein Beispiel mit mehr Varianten als br[Vokal]t?"

Comment: Ic halte die schiere Menge der rein theoretsch möglichen Antworten auf die Frage in ihrer aktuellen Form für ein Problem. Deswegen VTC als Too broad.

Comment: Nicht schließen! Das ist eine schöne Frage mit tollen Antworten!

Comment: @Vogel612 Die Frage ist für mich nicht wesentlich breiter gefaßt als "Gibt es ein deutsches Palindrom, das länger ist als 'Reliefpfeiler'?" Dass einige Antworten und Kommentare phonetische Gleichheit und Homonyme ins Spiel bringen und damit den "Lösungsraum" erweitern, ist der Frage m.E. nicht anzulasten. Mich stört das auch nicht, im Gegenteil.

Comment: Was ist mit Worten, die mehrere Vokale haben, da kann man an mehreren Stellen tauschen, siehe: Wagen, Wogen, Wagon.

Comment: @Matthias aktuell sieht das hier wie ein Rätsel aus ;) Wenn du einen Link hast, schiesse ich gerne auch auf die Frage.

Comment: @userunknown Ich glaube, es sollte immer an derselben Position getauscht werden. Sonst bekommst Du innerhalb der Gruppe dann auch Paare, sie sich in mehr als einem Vokal unterscheiden, z.B. Wogen und Wagon. Aber entscheiden kann das letztlich nur Toscho selbst.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke! Das Dehnungs-h bleibt also verboten, richtig?

Comment: @Matthias Ja, Dehnungs-h bleibt verboten.

Answer (score 4):

Bin kein Sprachexperte, aber ich versuch's mal :-)

Wagen (Auto), wagen (riskieren), wogen (Verb), Wogen (Wellen), wegen (durch), Wegen (auf Abwegen), wägen (abwägen), wögen (flektierte Form von wägen), wiegen, Waagen (Plural v. Waage), Wugen (Stadt in China), Wügen (Ort im Landkreis Dahme-Spreewald)

Comment: "wugen" ist auch eine alte Vergangenheit von "wagen"... nur so nebenbei

Comment: Und "wogen" ist auch die Vergangenheit von "wiegen".

Comment: Also Namen gelten nicht, würde ich sagen. Aber ansonsten ziemlich stark.

Comment: Groß-Klein-Schreibung soll unberücksichtigt bleiben. Wir ziehen 3x W*gen ab. Von der Fragestellung unberührt ist das Wort Wagon, welches auch nur in einem Vokal variiert, aber an anderer Position - die Frage hat nur eine Vokalposition und kommt so nicht in die Verlegenheit.

Answer (score 4):

> Ihr lieben `Leut`, mein `Leid` will ich euch klagen: alles ist aus dem
>   `Lot`!
>
> Ich dachte so bei mir: „`Lad` doch mal ein `Lied` von `Led` Zeppelin
>   herunter und hör’s dann ganz `laut`!“, also `lud` ich den Browser,
>   doch der `lädt` immer noch. Mein Rechner `litt` neulich schon an
>   Langsamkeit und ich habe nur einen `Latt`hammer aus `Lett`land zum
>   Reparieren.
>
> Darum `löt’` ich mir noch’n `Lütt` und Lütt hinter die Binde und gucke
>   eine `Late`-Night-Show mit Char`lotte` Roche und `Lud`ger Beerbaum.

Comment: Orthographisch nicht ganz korrekt, aber bis auf „`Led` Zeppelin“ phonetisch korrekt. Es lebe die Auslautverhärtung im Deutschen.

Comment: Unterscheidet sich ja nun nicht nur in einem Vokal.

Comment: @userunknown: Doch genau darin unterscheiden sich die markierten (Teil-)Wörter, sofern man Diphthonge als Vokale ansieht – alle erfüllen /l_t/. _Vokale_ sind eine phonologische Kategorie, keine graphematische. Dort kann man zwar auch von _Vokalbuchstaben_ reden, aber es gibt dafür auch unabhängige Termini wie _Kerngraphem_.

Answer (score 4):

**Lest**, mit welcher **List** die **Last** zur **Lust** wird. Na gut, ich weiß es nicht, vielleicht **lost** ja auch jemand eine Antwort. Hauptsache, der Hauptgewinn ist kein **Lost**, denn das ist ein Giftgas. *Leihst* du dir ein Auto, oder **least** du es? Mich **laust** der Affe: Jemand **liest** das hier? Dann **leist'** ich mir mal eine Behauptung: Diese Antwort **löst** die Aufgabe.

**Änderung:** "Leihst" ist nur noch kursiv statt fett, weil es nicht den formalen Anforderungen der Frage entspricht ("h" ist kein Vokal; danke an unser unknown für diesen Hinweis).

Comment: Das h in Leihst ist kein Vokal.

Comment: @userunknown: Für mich zählt das Dehnungs-h zur "Vokalgruppe" der Silbe, aber es ist in der Tat kein Vokal, insofern hast Du recht: Das Wort erfüllt nicht die formalen Anforderungen der Frage. Bleiben immer noch 11 Wörter :-)

Comment: @celtschk Die Frage ist gerade in dem Punkt, was genau ein Vokal ist, nicht besonders formal. Sonst gäbe es nicht den Disput zwischen Crissov und userunknown zu Crissovs Antwort. Von daher ist es für mich offen, ob "leihst" als Mitglied der l_st-Gruppe durchgeht.

Answer (score 4):

Ich glaube, ich kann noch mehr bieten:

- rate!
- die Rete - Steht zwar nicht im Duden und noch nicht mal im Deutschen Wörterbuch, ist aber laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolabium) und [Deutschem Museum](http://www.deutsches-museum.de/de/sammlungen/ausgewaehlte-objekte/meisterwerke-iii/astrolabium/) als "drehbare, netzartig durchbrochene Sternenscheibe" Teil des Astrolabiums, eines astronomischen Instruments. Geht für mich von daher als Fachbegriff durch.
- (die Reete - wäre wohl der Plural zu Reet (Schilf), wenn Reet überhaupt einen Plural hätte)
- [rite](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rite)
- riete - Konjunktiv zu raten
- rote (Tomaten)
- die Rute
- roote! - Imperativ zu "rooten" (sich Root-Rechte besorgen, insbesondere auf einem Android-Smartphone). Steht zwar (noch?) nicht im Duden, ist aber unter technophilen Android-Usern gebräuchlich.
- die Route
- die Räte - Plural zu Rat wie in Studenten-, Betriebs- und Stadtrat
- die Röte (ihrer Wangen)
- (Rüte  - Gemeinde/Bezirk in der Schweiz, aber Namen zählen ja nicht)
- die Raute
- die Räute - [der Griff eines Schlüssels](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4ute)
- reute - Vergangenheit von reuen (Es reute mich, daß...)
- reite!

Answer (score 1):

Ich komme auf **10**:

```
Last wie in Lastwagen 
laust Euch schon der Affe?
least er einen BMW? 
leist ich mir ein Eis? 
lest mehr Blogs! 
liest Dorit meinen Blog? 
List und Tücke 
löst sich der Gaumen 
lost einen Gewinner aus 
Lust durchwirkt das Becken
```

- Regelverstöße: Keine
- Fremdwörter: 1; least

Nach Hinweis aus dem Publikum, namentlich Matthias wurde

```
lauest ist das Windchen
```

entfernt, da es *au* und *e* zu zwei Silben gehören, und nicht ein Laut sind.

Methode: Ich habe ein PC-Wörterbuch benutzt (utf-german von Postgres:de), und folgende Befehlskette angewendet um ohne Unterscheidung von Groß/Kleinschreibung eine Liste von Wörter ohne Vokal zu bilden mit der Anzahl Fälle:

```
cat utf-german | tr "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÖÄÜY" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzöäüy" | \
sed -r 's/[AEIOUÄÜÖYaeiouäöüy]+/_/g;' | sort | count | sort -n | \
tail -n 100 > vokalignore4.lst
```

Das ersetzt relevante Großbuchstaben mit Kleinbuchstaben, dann Vokale und Umlaute - auch mehrere in Folge - durch einen Unterstrich, sortiert neu und zählt dann gleiche Zeilen, die numerisch sortiert werden und die 100 besten landen dann in einer Liste, vokalignore4.lst.

Last und last würden zwar so zweifach in der Liste landen, aber das ist leicht manuell zu korrigieren. Angeschaut werden muss das Ergebnis ohnehin. Außerdem werden viele Worte gefunden mit mehreren Stellen, die für Vokalersetzung in Frage kommen, etwa **7:    b_tr_t_t**.

Ich habe die Aufgabenstellung so verstanden, dass nur an einer Stelle getauscht werden darf.

Die Top-12 meiner Liste sind:

- 10:  l_g_
- 10:  l_st
- 10:  r_t_
- 10:  s_
- 10:  s_l_
- 10:  t_t_
- 11:  b_t_
- 11:  h_r_n
- 11:  r_t_n
- 12:  _
- 12:  b_s
- 12:  b_t_n
- 12:  l_g_n

Besonderes Augenmerk verdient die Liste reiner Vokale, die aber enttäuschendes enthält wie die Abkürzungen EU und AI als auch römische Ziffern wie II und III. 'a, e, i, ä' kann ich gar nicht erklären.

AI
Aue
EU
Ei
II
III
a
au
e
eo
i
ä

b_t_n enthält beispielsweise Bildungen wie Beton und Butan - ansonsten lauter Worte die auf en enden. Ähnlich ist es mit anderen Kandidaten, so dass ich nur nach Wörtern schaute mit nur einer heißen Stelle. Das führte dann zu l_st.

Da das Wörterbuch nicht alle Beugungen enthält, alle Geschlechter, Zeiten, den Imperativ, sind Funde die in der Liste weiter zurück sind vielleicht besser als erwartet. Auch ist das Wörterbuch nicht vollständig. Die Suche nach R_te liefert etwa nur 9 Ergebnisse:

- rate
- Räte
- raute
- reite
- riete
- rote
- Röte
- Route
- Rute

Comment: Ist das hier seit neustem eine Programmierseite oder was? Ich schlage vor, das als neue challenge auf [codegolf.se] zu posten....

Comment: @userunknown In "lauest" ersetzt Du einen Vokal(laut) durch zwei. Ich glaube, Toscho hat "nur in *einem* Vokal unterscheiden" auf Vokallaute bezogen. Wenn es ihm rein um Vokalbuchstaben (beliebiger Anzahl) gegangen wäre, hätte er ie, äu usw. nicht ausdrücklich mit Diphtongue und Vokallänge begründen müssen.

Comment: @Vogel612: Was spricht dagegen zu beschreiben, wie man auf eine Antwort gekommen ist?

Comment: @Vogel612: Die Beschreibung dient dazu, dass andere auf dem Verfahren aufbauend andere Buchstabenkombinationen untersuchen können oder das Verfahren weiter verbessern oder auf andere Wörterbücher anwenden, die bei denen so rumliegen. Du bist aber eingeladen eine solche Challenge selbst auf Code Golf zu posten.

Comment: @Matthias: Das habe ich gar nicht überlegt. Werde es korrigieren.