# Größte Menge deutscher Wörter, deren Aussprache sich nur durch Variation eines Vokals unterscheidet

Tags: vowel, curiosity

Ich suche eine möglichst große Liste von deutschen Wörtern, deren **Aussprache** sich nur durch Variation eines Vokals bzw. Polyphthongs (Diphthong usw.) unterscheidet, also das größte deutsche [Minimaltupel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalpaar), z. B.:

> wagst (vaːkst), weckst (vɛkst), wuchst (vuːkst), …

[Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/13654/2594) ist die analoge Frage für Unterschiede in der Schreibung.

Der veränderte Vokal sollte dabei immer derselbe sein, Folgendes ist also keine gültige Liste:

> Lasso, lasse, ließe, …

Folgende Kriterien werde ich zur Akzeptanz einer Antwort heranziehen. Ich bitte aber darum, Wörter, die hiergegen verstoßen, trotzdem aufzulisten, damit wir nicht irgendwann für jeden denkbaren Satz an Kriterien eine eigene Frage haben:

- Wörter, deren Aussprache identisch ist, werden nur mehrfach gezählt, wenn sie verschieden geschrieben werden (um sicherzugehen, dass sie wenig miteinander zu tun haben).
- Verschiedene Vokallängen zählen getrennt.
- Natürliche Verkürzungen sind erlaubt, z. B. *wögst* statt *wögest.*
- Wortteile zählen nicht.
- Es zählen nur Wörter, die im Duden stehen.
- Dialekt-Aussprachen zählen nicht.
- [Hiats](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiat) zählen nicht als ein Polyphthong, z. B. ist *blaues* nicht kombinierbar mit *bloß.*

Ich bitte darüber die Antworten der Übersicht halber als Listen in folgender Reihenfolge zu gestalten: *a, e, i, o, u, ä, ö, ü* (jeweils lang und kurz), *au, äu/eu, ei/ai,* sonstige. Man beachte, dass das kurze *ä* und *e* aussprachegleich sind. Unter *sonstige* fallen Vokale, die nur in Fremdwörtern vorkommen, und alles, was [in dieser Tabelle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal#Vokale_im_Deutschen) auf der rechten Seite steht.

Comment: Das ist wahrlich eine präzise Spezifikation! Aber warum hast Du Deine hierzu passende, ursprünglich bei der verlinkten Frage gegebene und dort offenbar inzwischen gelöschte eigene Antwort hier nicht gleich gepostet?

Comment: Irgendwo eine Wortliste einschließlich IPA-Aussprache auftreiben, und dann ein kleines Programm darauf loslassen? Wenn jemand eine Wortliste kennt, könnte ich das Programm notfalls schnell schreiben.

Comment: @dirkt: Ich bezweifle, dass eine solche Liste existiert, zumal man ja alle Flektionsformen benötigt. Im Wiktionary findet man zwar auch Aussprachen für einige flektierte Formen, aber bei weitem nicht alles. Man kann das natürlich zumindest nutzen, um heiße Kandidaten zu identifizieren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [b*t] – 22 Wörter

- ***bat*** – 1. und 3. Person Singular Imperfekt von *bitten*
- ***Bad*** – Sanitärraum
- *Baht* – thailändische Währung
- kurzes *a* fehlt.
- ***bet*** – Verkürzung *bete,* Imperativ oder 1. Person Singular zu *beten*
- ***Beet*** – Blumenbeet
- ***Bett*** – Schlafstätte
- ***biet*** – Verkürzung von *biete,* Imperativ Singular von *bieten*
- [***Beat***](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beat_Rhythmus) – Rhythmus
- ***bitt*** – Verkürzung von *bitte,* Imperativ Singular von *bitten*
- ***Bit*** – Informationseinheit
- ***bot*** – 1. und 3. Person Singular Imperfekt von *bieten*
- ***Boot*** – Wasserfahrzeug
- [***Bott***](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bott)
- *Bot* – Kurzform von *Roboter,* nicht im Duden
- ***buht*** – erste Person Singular Präsens von [*buhen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/buhen)
- ***boot*** – Imperativ Singular zu [*booten*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/booten)
- ***[Butt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Butt)*** – Scholle (bekannt aus *Heilbutt*)
- ***bät*** – Verkürzung von *bäte,* 1. und 3. Person Konjunktiv II von *bitten*
- ***böt*** – Verkürzung von *böte,* 1. und 3. Person Konjunktiv II von *bieten*
- kurzes *ö* fehlt
- langes *ü* fehlt
- [***Bütt***](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Buett)
- ***baut*** – 3. Person Singular Präsens von *bauen*
- ***Baud*** – Informationsübertragungseinheit
- ***beut*** – aus der Mode gekommene 3. Person Singular Präsens von *bieten*
- ***Byte*** – Informationseinheit

Comment: Was, der Duden kennt `booten`, aber nicht `rooten`? Gemeinheit! - Spaß beiseite: Chapeau, vor allem für die Spürnase zu `Bott` und `beut`! Man könnte sogar streiten, ob man 22 Wörter zählt, da der Duden zwei verschiedene Aussprachen für Baud kennt.

Answer (score 3):

## [l*kst] – 15 Wörter

- ***lagst*** – 2. Person Singular Imperfekt von *liegen*
- ***lackst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [*lacken*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lacken) (mit Lack überziehen)
- ***legst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *legen*
- ***leckst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *lecken*
- ***liegst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *liegen*
- Kurzes *i* fehlt.
- ***logst*** – 2. Person Singular Imperfekt von *lügen*
- ***lockst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *locken*
- ***loggst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [*loggen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/loggen)
- ***lugst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [*lugen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lugen)
- ***luchst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [*luchsen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/luchsen)
- ***lägst*** – 2. Person Singular Konjunktiv II von *liegen*
- ***lögst*** – Verkürzung von *lögest,* 2. Person Singular Konjunktiv II von *lügen*
- ***löckst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [löcken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/loecken)
- ***lügst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *lügen*
- ***laugst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von [*laugen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/laugen)
- *äu/eu* fehlt.
- *ei/ai* fehlt.

---

Aufgrund der Nachfrage hier noch die ähnliche Reihe auf **[v*kst]** (11 Wörter)

- ***wagst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wagen*
- ***wachst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wachsen* (mit Wachs versehen)
- be*wegst* – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *bewegen*
- ***weckst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wecken,* aussprachegleich zu *wächst*
- ***wiegst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wiegen*
- ***wichst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wichsen*
- ***wogst*** – 2.  Person Singular Imperfekt von *wiegen*
- kurzes *o* fehlt – vielleicht irgendwas mit *Wok?*
- ***wuchst*** – 2.  Person Singular und Plural Imperfekt von *wachsen* (größer werden)
- kurzes *u* fehlt
- ***wägst*** – 2. Person Singular Präsens von *wägen* (»Du wägst ab«)
- ***wächst*** – 2.  Person Singular Präsens von *wachsen* (größer werden), aussprachegleich zu *weckst*
- ***wögst*** – Verkürzung von *wögest,* 2. Person Singular Konjunktiv II von *wiegen*
- kurzes *ö* fehlt
- ***wüchst*** – Verkürzung von *wüchset,* 2. Person Plural Konjunktiv II von *wachsen*

Answer (score 3):

### [r*tə] – 18 Wörter

basierend auf meiner [Antwort auf die Schwesterfrage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/semantische-vokalvielfalt/15171#15171); für den Hinweis auf Ratte, rette, ritte und Rotte geht mein Dank an [Wrzlprmft](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2594/wrzlprmft)

- die **Rate**
- die **Ratte**
- langes e fehlt; die Rete (Teil des Astrolabiums) steht nicht im Duden
- **rette** - 1.P. Sing. Präs. sowie Imperativ zu retten
- **[rite](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rite)**
- **riete** - Konjunktiv zu raten
- **ritte** - Konjunktiv zu reiten
- **rote** Tomaten
- die **Rotte**
- die **Rute**
- **ruhte** - Vergangenheit von ruhen
- roote - 1. P. Sing. Präs. sowie Imperativ zu "rooten" (sich Root-Rechte besorgen, insbesondere auf einem Android-Smartphone); nicht im Duden verzeichnet
- die **Route**
- die **Räte** - Plural zu Rat wie in Studenten-, Betriebs- und Stadtrat
- die **Röte** ihrer Wangen
- kurzes ö fehlt
- langes ü fehlt - Rüte (Gemeinde/Bezirk in der Schweiz) steht nicht im Duden
- kurzes ü fehlt - [Rütte](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCtte) ist aber der Name mehrerer Orte und Personen
- die **Raute**
- **raute** - Vergangenheit von rauen (unterscheidet sich von Raute durch die Kleinschreibung und hat auch nichts damit zu tun)
- die Räute ([der Griff eines Schlüssels](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A4ute)) steht nicht im Duden, aber immerhin im Deutschen Wörterbuch
- **reute** - Vergangenheit von reuen (Es reute mich, daß...)
- **reite** - 1. P. Sing. Präs. sowie Imperativ zu reiten
- **reihte** - Vergangenheit zu reihen

Comment: Man koennte argumentieren, dass niemand, der das Wort "rooten" verwendet, es mit dt. R aussprechen würde ... aber eine beeindruckende Liste!

Comment: @jona Danke für die Blumen :-) Meine persönliche Erfahrung geht eher in die andere Richtung: innerhalb eines deutschen Satzes wird in meinem Umfeld auch für das englische root ein deutsches R gesprochen. Ich habe noch nicht darauf geachtet, würde  mich aber nicht wundern, wenn ich da auch selbst dazugehöre.