# Gibt es deutsche Mythen über (superlative) Eigenschaften der deutschen Sprache?

Tags: sociolinguistics, culture

Viele Sprachen hegen und pflegen verschiedene Mythen oder angenommene „Fakten“ über sich selbst. Z.B. die bekannte angebliche Tatsache, dass in irgendeiner inuitischen  Sprache, „Schnee“ mit einem Wort sehr präzise beschrieben werden könnte, und zwar so, dass in andere Sprachen mehrere Sätze nötig wären, wenn überhaupt möglich;  oder dass Englisch die Sprache  mit dem größten Wortschatz wäre. Im Schwedischen hätten wir als einzige Sprache der Welt ein Wort für „nicht zu viel und nicht zu wenig“, „lagom“. Die Französische sei natürlich die allerschönste. Sei es wie es will mit der Wahrheit dieser Aussagen, sie sind aber sehr verbreitet.

Meine Frage: Welche Mythen oder „Fakten“, die die deutsche Sprache von anderen Sprachen unterscheidet, und die als "einmalig" gelten, pflegen die Deutschsprachigen?

Comment: Bezüglich Eskimos und Schnee: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo-W%C3%B6rter_f%C3%BCr_Schnee

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/26577

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Von deiner Antwort versteh ich, dass du meine Frage falsch verstanden hast,  es ist mir jetzt nachvollziehbar warum du sie für breit haltest.. Nur Punkt 6 ist was ich mir gedacht habe, und dies war mir tatsächlich auch bekannt ;) Hab die Überschrift editiert um die Frage zu begrenzen und hoffe, dass sie nicht weggestimmt wird. :)

Comment: @Beta: Die Frage im Titel gefällt mir schon besser; ich würde aber noch die eigentliche Frage etwas anpassen; sonst überliest das garantiert wer. Außerdem würde ich Antworten à la »einzige Sprachen mit einem Wort für …« ausschließen, da dieser Aspekt alleine für unzählige umstrittene Antworten herhalten kann.

Comment: Meines Wissens gilt die deutsche Sprache als sehr präzise (sowohl in der Aussprache als auch in der Wortwahl, letzteres wohl durch die zusammengesetzten Substantive). Allerdings ist mir hier kein Superlativ bekannt.

Comment: Die meisten dieser Mythen sind Quatsch. Siehe Jans link. Großer Quatsch ist auch die Aussage, Englisch habe die meisten Wörter. Ein großes Problem ist noch, was als unterschiedliche Wörter durchgeht. Griechische Nationalisten haben die stupide Technik, auf der diese Behauptung basiert auf einen kleinen Teil des Lexikons angewandt und 70 Millionen griechische Wörter gefunden. Deutsch und Altgriechisch können beliebig viele Wörter durch verlängern erzeugen. Chinesisch kennt um die 100.000 Zeichen, die man sehr oft kombinieren kann....

Comment: Zu Schnee im Grönländischen: http://www.belleslettres.eu/blog/stefanowitsch-schnee-eskimo.php

Comment: Deutsch gilt als schwierig, als präzise, als zu verschachtelten Nebensätzen einladend und zu Wortungetümen. Dass es dabei eine Extremstellung einnimmt (die schwierigste, die längsten Wörter, die verschachtelsten Sätze...) ist mir nicht bekannt oder als These begegnet, daher fehlt wohl der Aspekt des Mythos. Satz- und Wortlänge ließe sich messen. Präzision und Schwierigkeitsgrad dürften schwer überprüfbar sein.

Comment: @Jan: Dass Deutsch harsch klingt ist aber wohl eine Beobachtung, besser ein Hörerlebnis, dass wohl vornehmlich von Außen wahrgenommen wird. Für den Deutschen gilt Deutsch ja als normal. Btw. wäre es hilfreich den Link zu labeln, etwa "duplicate Post" oder "siehe hier", oder was soll uns der Link sagen?

Comment: @userunknown wahrscheinlich hätte ich ein *related* oder *teilweise relevant* davorschreiben können; er sollte nur darauf hindeuten, dass diese andere Frage existiert. Ich halte die beiden für kein Duplikat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deutsch wird gemeinhin gern als **Die Sprache der Dichter und Denker** bezeichnet, da viele Poeten, Künstler und Gelehrte diese Sprache nutzten oder nutzen.

Darüber hinaus ist Deutsch für seine zusammengesetzten Substantive mit einer deutlichen Überlänge bekannt; obwohl es auf keinen Fall die einzige Sprache der Welt ist, die dieses Phänomen sein eigen nennt (siehe agglutinierende Sprachen).

Ein weit verbreitetes Bild der deutschen Sprache ist, dass sie hart und unangenehm klingt, ja wie militärische Befehle. Die Geschichte des zweiten Weltkriegs dürfte zu diesem Klischee ein gutes Stück beigetragen haben.

Was das umstrittene Thema *Wörter, die es in keiner anderen Sprache gibt* angeht, hat das Deutsche viele Begriffe, die tatsächlich sehr schwierig zu übersetzen sind und daher sogar manchmal in ihrer ursprünglichen Form in anderen Sprachen benutzt werden:

- Weltschmerz ([Englische Wikipedia über Weltschmerz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weltschmerz))
- [Lösungs-]Ansatz (Z.B. im [Englischen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz), im [Französischen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) und im [Portugiesischen](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) ein etablierter Begriff)
- Fernweh
- Zweisamkeit
- sich lieben lernen
- Ohrwurm
- Eintopf ([Im Polnischen heißt Eintopf auch *Eintopf*](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eintopf))

Comment: Zumindest bei _Weltschmerz_ und _Ansatz_ hat es sicherlich weniger mit der Deutschen Sprache an sich zu tun dass diese Begriffe international verwendet werden, als einfach damit dass die wichtigen frühen Publikationen zu diesen Themen auf Deutsch erschienen sind. [Eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) ist ein noch stärkeres Beispiel: zweifellos ließe sich das Konzept genausogut mit Englischen Begriffen ausdrücken, aber der Deutsche Begriff war anscheinend etabliert bevor jemand einen solchen Begriff dagegengesetzt hätte.

Comment: Übrigens fällt mir hier gerade auf wieviel am Klischee über die Sperrigkeit der Deutschen Sprache tatsächlich dran ist – ich habe seit Jahren kaum etwas außer Kurznachrichten in meiner Muttersprache geschrieben, und ich finde es jetzt richtig schwierig mich mal wieder darin schriftlich auszudrücken!

Comment: Auch das [aufbau priciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle), das [leitmotif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif) oder der [sprachraum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachraum) sind Wörter, die in ihren jeweiligen Fachgebieten internationale Fachbegriffe sind.

Comment: "Schadenfreude", "Kopfkino", usw. Ich finde "sich lieben lernen" und "Ohrwurm" nicht typisch deutsch, dafür gibt es in anderen Sprachen auch Begriffe. Und ja, Deutsch ist sperrig. Niederländisch übrigens auch.

Answer (score 5):

- die walisischste Wortsubstantivierungslängenmaximierungsgrenzwertfreiheit  aller Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaften
- Deutsch = deutlichst, English = engelsgleichst, Francais = frankst und freist
- das kasernenhoftönigste Befehlsgebell

Comment: It would be interesting to read the above answer in English.

Answer (score 3):

Nicht notwendigerweise eine Eigenschaft der Sprache selbst, aber ein wichtiges Merkmal für den Umgang damit und die Kultur um sie herum:

Während in englischsprachigen Ländern die Auffassung herrscht, dass ein Stück geschriebene Sprache umso "besser" ist, je einfacher es geschrieben und je verständlicher es ist ("Auf den Punkt", mit kurzen Sätzen und einfacher Wortwahl), hinterlässt unser deutscher Umgang mit Sprache manchmal den Eindruck "was schwer zu schreiben war, muss auch schwer zu lesen sein". Dies trifft besonders auf Schriftstücke zu, die z.B. technische oder andere wissenschaftliche Sachverhalte betreffen.

Dem Deutschen hängt hier etwas der Ruf der Komplexität an, wir neigen dazu, Sachverhalte komplexer auszudrücken, als es oft notwendig ist - Vielleicht, weil wir die sprachliche Kompetenz eines Schreibers leicht mit seiner fachlichen Kompetenz vermischen.

Comment: Hm, ich weiß nicht – auch Englischsprachige wissenschaftliche Arbeiten drücken sich z.T. viel komplizierter aus als für den Sachverhalt nötig wäre.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Der Unterschied ist, dass bei uns der Text mit wachsender Komplexität gefühlt "besser" wird - Im Englischen wird er dadurch gefühlt "schlechter"

Answer (score 0):

Man findet immer wieder englischsprachige Seiten im Internet, die Deutsch für seine "grossartigen" Wortschöpfungen preisen - gemeint sind meist zusammengesetzte Substantive und besonders treffende Umschreibungen.

http://www.fluentu.com/german/blog/weird-german-words-vocabulary/

https://www.buzzfeed.com/awesomer/better-german-words

https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/favorite-german-words

Das ist aber zugegebenermassen keine genaue Antwort auf die gestellte Frage, da dies kein *deutscher* Mythos ist - wir Deutschsprachigen nehmen das als selbstverständlich hin.